# Search in current folder with helm-do-grep

Tags: search, emacs, emacs-helm

I have so small problem about in Emacs. I bind `helm-do-grep` command for Emacs. It's really useful.

I want to search something in current folder.
I searched some codes about that both of them are working but I don't have ability to fix them like what I want.

If you fix them for me I'll be happy thank you.

```lisp
(defvar my/book-notes-directory "~/Dropbox/books")
(defun my/helm-do-grep-book-notes ()
"Search my book notes."
(interactive)
(helm-do-grep-1 (list my/book-notes-directory)))


(defun my-dir-locals-dir ()
"Return the directory local variables directory.
Code taken from `hack-dir-local-variables'."
(let ((variables-file (dir-locals-find-file (or (buffer-file-name) default-directory)))
    (dir-name nil))
(cond,
 ((stringp variables-file)
  (setq dir-name (file-name-directory variables-file)))
 ((consp variables-file)
  (setq dir-name (nth 0 variables-file))))
dir-name))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
(defun my/helm-do-grep-current-directory-tree ()
  "Recursively search current directory.
If a parent directory has a `dir-locals-file', use that as the
root instead."
  (interactive)
  (let ((variables-file (dir-locals-find-file
                         (or (buffer-file-name) default-directory))))
    (helm-do-grep-1
     (list
      (cond
       ((stringp variables-file)
        (file-name-directory variables-file))
       ((consp variables-file)
        (nth 0 variables-file))
       (t default-directory)))
     t nil '("*"))))
```

By the way, if you ask on http://emacs.stackexchange.com , you might get better answers. (And faster, too!) =)